# unable to refresh windows after setting the global proxy settings

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to enable/disable the windows global proxy( in Internet option ) using windows registry. If I set the value, I don't have any problems but refreshing the settings. After searching I found a question on SO that provided the code for that. But now the problem is that In each session of the app it works only once. i.e. it works the first time and if you want it to work again, you have to rerun the app. Any ideas what could be the problem??? here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SystemProxyToggle
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
        public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
        public const int INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;
        public const int INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
        static bool settingsReturn, refreshReturn;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            queryStatus();
        }

        private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toggleStatus();
            queryStatus();
        }

        private void queryStatus()
        {
            RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
            int status = (int)registry.GetValue("ProxyEnable");
            if (status == 0)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Proxy Is Disabled";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Proxy Is Enabled";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }

            //I added this after I encountered the problem
            //though I don't that this is the problem
            registry.Close();
        }

        private void toggleStatus()
        {
            RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
            int status = (int)registry.GetValue("ProxyEnable");
            if (status == 1)
            {
                registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
            }
            //Refresh System Settings
            settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

            //I added this after I encountered the problem
            registry.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think i quite understand your question, i just executed your code and it appears to work as expected. I run it, shows me the proxy is disabled. I press the button and proxy gets enabled, Press it again and it gets disabled.. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Same here, no problem running the code.

Comment: A completely wild guess, since other people can run your program successfully, do you have any software installed that protect your registry? Antivirus? Perhaps some domain controlled thing? I once had a weird problem that my IE start page got reset all the time, no matter what I did, editing the registry in various ways. It turned out to be because it got pushed through the domain my computer was on.

Comment: As far as I know and I'm 99% sure I don't have any program of such kind. Plus I have tried the code without InternetSetOption calls and the registry gets changed flawlessly. Although thanks for the comments everyone.

Comment: @tweellt: Did you copy&paste my code? If so what's your Win version?

Comment: @Dayan: It just works once. The second time I press the button, nothing gets changed. Neither the label nor the actual value in the registry.

Comment: @mnVoh, I tryed your code and the registry.GetValue("ProxyEnable") correctly changes from 0 to 1 and vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else stuck on this issue, something odd seemed to do the trick for me.

I simply removed/commented all calls to InternetSetOption()

```
//settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
//refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

Restarted the program and this time the registry changes took effect in both directions as long as I wanted and not just the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this code in Windows 7 (Internet Explorer 11) and had no problems, but when I tried in a second system with Windows 8, I had the same result as you did.

After digging for a while I found out that you should call `InternetSetOption` differently, basically like this:

```
INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 95

InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

I tried it again on both systems and it worked just fine.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately what you suggest doesn't solve my problem. I added you call with and without INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED. And I'm running Win7_x64

Comment: That's odd, it worked fine on my side with INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED!